# Creating a table of User Logins per Day, having trouble grouping them

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping

I have the query below that is giving me an error at the AND, saying my <= sign is not valid there. I am not sure how to correct this.

```
-- User Logins Per Day
SELECT
  DATE(created_time_stamp),
  security_profile_id AS Name,
  COUNT(*) AS logins,
  CASE
    WHEN COUNT(security_profile_id) <= 1
    THEN “one_session”
    WHEN COUNT(security_profile_id) > 1 AND <= 3
    THEN “two_to_three_sessions”
    ELSE “four_plus_sessions”
END AS sessions_summary
FROM session
WHERE security_profile_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  DATE(created_time_stamp),
  Name
ORDER BY
  DATE(created_time_stamp),
  Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a value to compare with `3`.

```
WHEN COUNT(security_profile_id) > 1 AND COUNT(security_profile_id) <= 3
```

But there's no need to test `> 1` in the first place, since the first `WHEN` condition handles all the values `<=1`. So just change it to:

```
WHEN COUNT(security_profile_id) <= 3
```

And more generally, you can use `BETWEEN` if you want to test if a number is between two values. It's inclusive, so the equivalent expression would be

```
WHEN COUNT(security_profile_id) BETWEEN 2 AND 3
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed that issue, I really appreciate your help. It's now telling me that my column names are not working, the "one_session" "two_to_three" etc. I am creating these columns right? I thought I could name them whatever I needed so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong there. I can't express my gratitude enough for your reply!

Comment: one_session, etc, are row values, not column names.  maybe take a step back and think about what you want your results to look like and show us?  also, in your title you say "creating a table", but don't seem to be trying to do that.

Comment: @CaseyBData Those are values of the `sessions_summary` column, not column names themselves.

Comment: Thank you both very much for the help, I definitely understand what you're saying. My original query: -- User Logins Per Day
SELECT
  DATE(created_time_stamp),
  security_profile_id AS Name,
  COUNT(*) AS logins
FROM session
WHERE security_profile_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  DATE(created_time_stamp),
  Name
ORDER BY
  DATE(created_time_stamp),
  Name
 gets me the data broken up by how many sessions each user had on a particular day.

Comment: Sorry hit enter on accident. What I was trying to do above is further break down this data by separating the values by how many sessions they had each day. For example: 80 users had 2-3 sessions per day, 28 users had one session per day.

Comment: You can use this as a subquery in another query that uses `GROUP BY sessions_summary`

Comment: And you are correct, I'm not trying to create a table just write a query that breaks up the data by "intensity" so I can turn that query into a metric on a dashboard. Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 0):

A valid expression is expected after the `AND` you're referring to, `<= 3` is not valid, you probably want to write `WHEN COUNT(security_profile_id) > 1 AND COUNT(security_profile_id) <= 3`.

Therefore:

```sql
-- User Logins Per Day
SELECT
  DATE(created_time_stamp),
  security_profile_id AS Name,
  COUNT(*) AS logins,
  CASE
    WHEN COUNT(security_profile_id) <= 1
    THEN “one_session”
    WHEN COUNT(security_profile_id) > 1 AND COUNT(security_profile_id) <= 3
    THEN “two_to_three_sessions”
    ELSE “four_plus_sessions”
END AS sessions_summary
FROM session
WHERE security_profile_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  DATE(created_time_stamp),
  Name
ORDER BY
  DATE(created_time_stamp),
  Name
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed that issue, I really appreciate your help. It's now telling me that my column names are not working, the "one_session" "two_to_three" etc. I am creating these columns right? I thought I could name them whatever I needed so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong there. I can't express my gratitude enough for your reply!

Comment: These are not columns, actually, the actual column name being created (only for the scope of your query, they are not created in the database) is `sessions_summary`, and the possible values for this column are defined in your CASE/WHEN/THEN, which are one_session, two_to_three_sessions, four_plus_sessions.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for clarifying that! I am essentially trying to break down my sessions data by how many times a user logged in (one session/day, 2-3 sessions/day, 4+sessions/day) am I headed in the right direction to do so?

Comment: It looks correct. I just don't think you need to break down the number of times a user has logged in only 3 categories, you can just store the number of times the user has logger in (whatever number it is) and categorize it in your front-end, if you're using this query to display it in a front-end, of course, otherwise, it looks pretty good.

Comment: Oh, I just read your other response, in the cases that you want a number of occurences of each type (1 sess/day, 2~3 sess/day, 4+) then this is the way to go. (Essentially a histogram).

Comment: Thank you so much Lucas, I hope you have a wonderful day!